How to calculate average of a column that has text?
I have two columns. Column A is month year. Column B is title of a document. I have to show a simple line chart showing how many documents were created by month-year and then show a total average across all month years. i have tried averagex and created variables but the average is showing me per month instead of all the months.
so for example:

jan 2018 - 30 (count of documents)
feb 2018 - 50 (count of documents)
march 2018 - 15 (count of documents)

when I try to plot the average, it's showing me again 30, 50, 15 INSTEAD of 31.6 which is the average of 30,50,15). Can someone please help?
I tried both average and creating a measure but both are showing me average per month instead of average of the whole data

Try sharing the current DAX formula. Do you have an example of the model?

Look at using ALLSELECTED or ALL in your calculation to get either all the data in the visual (ALLSELECTED) or all the data in a table (ALL).

here is the sample data



year month
document




jan2018
a


jan2018
b


feb2018
c


feb2018
d


feb2018
e


mar2018
f


mar2018
g


mar2018
h


mar2018
i


mar2018
j



avg =
DIVIDE (
    CALCULATE ( COUNT ( 'Table'[document] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) ),
    CALCULATE ( DISTINCTCOUNT ( 'Table'[year month] ), ALL ( 'Table' ) )
)



hi Ryan, I was able to do this and it is showing me the correct average. However, now when i add a slicer to it and lets say I select the first three months, the average isnt changing and showing me the average of the first three months. it is still showing me the average of all the year months instead of the year months selected. can you please help me adjust the formula?

you can change ALL to ALLSELECT to have a try
